# Background Color based on page variable PHP

Tags: php

Looking for a shed of light on my idea. New to PHP and just need some tips on making page backgrounds different based on varibles.

I have three pages:

Page 1
Page 2
Page 3.

Each of these pages needs a different background colour.

My PHP looks like this:

```
$service = page1;

if ($service == "page1")
{
echo "YOUR ON PAGE ONE";
}
```

This statement works, however, i feel like there is a better way to do it. I believe the variable should be on each page but i think the best way might be to create a function in a seperate functions.php file and create the if statement?

Comment: This really depends on *how* complex you want to get... you *could* store everything in a database, including a per-page *"theme"* and load that in based on the request URI ... which means this question like likely to be far too broad.

Comment: whatabout having a simple css class that you set per page? There are uncountable ways to do this, and as CD001 said, it totally depends on how flexible/complicated or simple/hardcoded you want it. If it's really just three pages I'd go for 3 css classes in `<body class="page1">`

Comment: Save in session in order to access every page. And better way use switch statement.

Comment: other solutions may include a seperate settings file, that has an array or class with the mapped background settings. You could even go the database way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many comments have pointed out there are 100 ways to skin a cat. Here's one-way using sessions.

```
// always.php
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Setup mapping between pages and their colour
$colourMapping = [
    'page1.php' => 'red',
    'page2.php' => 'green',
    'page3.php' => 'blue',
];

// Store that mapping into the session
$_SESSION['colourMapping'] = $colourMapping;
```

---

```
// page1.php
<?php
// Bring in the always.php file which will automatically start the session
require_once('always.php');

// Grab the colour mapping from the session
$mapping = $_SESSION['colourMapping'];
?>

<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: <?php echo $mapping['page1.php']; ?>
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    I'm page1.php
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
// page2.php
<?php
// Bring in the always.php file which will automatically start the session
require_once('always.php');

// Grab the colour mapping from the session
$mapping = $_SESSION['colourMapping'];
?>

<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: <?php echo $mapping['page2.php']; ?>
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    I'm page2.php
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like your starting to run in the old problem of static PHP files and how to pass information around to them. You might want to consider looking into a framework if you're getting serious about PHP development. They've solved issues like this and are really geared towards speeding up development. That being said, there's is nothing wrong with hand-coded PHP files and you learn very quickly but beware that you can pick up a lot of bad practices quickly which take a long time to unlearn.

Comment: whatabout using `__FILE__` to get the current script?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<?php
    $service = "page1";

    if ($service == "page1"){
        $backgroundColorPage = "#00bbe6";
    } elseif ($service == "page2"){
        $backgroundColorPage = "#f44336";
    } else {
        $backgroundColorPage = "#28a745";
    }
?>

<html>
    <body style="background-color: <?php echo $backgroundColorPage; ?>">
        <p>Hi! I'm a colored page by PHP :)</p>
    </body>
</html>
```